# Incrementing in java

Tags: java, nested

I have to throw an `IllegalArgumentException` if the month and day is not a valid date in 2015. Return a date formatted as month/day/year, e.g., 12/9/2015, that occurs 3 days after the given month and day in 2015

```
public static String getReturnDate(int month, int day) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    int year = 2015;
    String s4 = (month + "/" + day + "/" + year);
    String s5 = ("Invalid response");
    String s6 = ("None");
    if ((month < 1 ||  month > 12) && (day < 1 || day > 31)) {
        return s5;
    }
    if ((month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 9 || month == 11) && (day > 30)) {
        return s5;
    }
    if((month == 1 || month == 2 || month ==3 || month ==5 || month == 7 || month == 8 || month == 10 || month == 12) && (day > 31)) {
        return s5;
    }
    if ((month == 2) && (day > 28)) { 
        return s5;
    } 
    else if((month >= 1 ||  month <= 12) && (day >= 1 || day <= 31)) {
        return s4;
    }
    if ((month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 9 || month == 11) && (day <= 30)) {
        return s4;
    }
    if((month == 1 || month == 2 || month ==3 || month ==5 || month == 7 || month == 8 || month == 10 || month == 12) && (day <= 31)) {
        return s4;
    }
    if ((month == 2) && (day < 28)) {
        return s4;
    } 
    return s4 + 3;
}
```

Comment: Indent your code by four spaces and it will appear as code.

Answer (score 1):

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
```

Set your date in the cal object. Then use following line of code.

```
Calendar.add(Calendar.DAY, 3);
```

And you can use

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
String dateString = dateFormat.format(cal);
```

To get the date in the required format rather than concatenating string.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning on an error, throw an Exception, eg

```
if ((month < 1 || month > 12){ 
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Bad month");
}
```

The following section is redundant as you have already checked for more than 31 days in the month

```
if((month == 1 || month == 2 || month ==3 || month ==5 || month == 7 || month == 8 || month == 10 || month == 12) && (day > 31)) {
    return s5;
}
```

This line terminates your method as you have already checked for invalid dates

```
else if((month >= 1 ||  month <= 12) && (day >= 1 || day <= 31)) {
    return s4;
}
```

Instead, at this point, you should add three days to the date and update the month and year if necessary.

I presume that this is supposed to be a test of your programming skills rather than your knowledge of Java APIs, so you want an array to store the number of days in the month, such as

```
int days[] = { 0, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};
```

and then to check if `day + 3` is still in the same month, use

```
day += 3;
while (day > days[month]) {
    day -= days[month];
    month++;
}
```

Similarly check if the year has changed.  The `while` loop is a start of generalising the code to handle increments greater than three.

Then go back and use the array to simplify your error checking.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String getReturnDate(int month, int day) throws IllegalArgumentException {
                    int year = 2015;
                    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                    Calendar.add(Calendar.DAY, 3);
                    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
                    String dateString = dateFormat.format(cal);
                    String s4 = (month + "/" + day + "/" + year);
                    if ((month < 1 ||  month > 12) && (day < 1 || day > 31)) {
                        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid response");
                    }
                    int days[] = {0, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};
                    day = day + 3;
                    if (day > days[month]) {
                        month++;
                    }
                    if (day > day[year]) {
                        year++;
                    }
                }
```